# Typeset is disabled for TexShop in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: typography

The typeset button is not highlighted and does not compile new text. I can open an existing source file and it displays the corresponding pdf. But when I edit the source, it does not compile.  Even a newly created source does not compile.

I just moved my system from my old MacBook to a new one.

TexShop version is 4.51.

New computer:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020), macOS BigSur Version 11.0.1, TexShop 4.51 (4.51)
Typeset button is dimmed.
Does not compiled new source code.  Will read and compile an existing source file.

Old computer:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017), macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7,TexShop 4.51 (4.51)
Typeset button is not dimmed. Just as bright as other buttons.
Does not compiled new source code.  Will read and compile an existing source file.

I have tried creating a new source file and compiling it.  This does not work.

I have put the TexShop application and folder in the trash, and re-installed a new one from the website.  Did not work.

Can anyone get TexShop to work under macOS Big Sur?

Any fixes out there?

Any help appreciated.

Nathan Haese
Lafayette, CA

Comment: you have the editor, texshop, but have you installed tex (usually mactex for a mac)?

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? Was it installed by MacTeX or some other way? What does `which pdflatex` return in Terminal? If you create a .TeX file, save it, quit TeXShop and re-open it does it compile? Also, report this to the author of TeXShop.

Comment: Just as a comment, TeXShop 4.51 not only runs under Big Sur but it is a universal application so it runs native under an M1 (ARM) system.

Answer (score 2):

Nathan later notified me that the program is now working. He installed BasicTeX and threw away the old Preference File, forcing TeXShop to generate a new one. One of these actions solved the problem.